# File too Large python

Tags: python, ubuntu, file-io

I am writing to a file using python. The script suddenly stops running and throws an 'IOError: [Errno 27] File too large'
Is there a limit on the size of the file that you are allowed to create using a program? 
Has anyone else faced this issue?
The file size was close to 4.3Gb(it is a bit big) when it stopped.

Comment: It didn't happen to get to 4294967295 bytes (ie 2^32-1) did it?

Comment: I just checked the file size, it is 4.3 GB (4,294,967,295 bytes)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This [Python bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue9271) indicates that the OS is the source of this error message, not Python.

Since you are writing to a FAT partition, and the maximum file size limit is 4GB for FAT 32 ([LinuxFilesystemsExplained](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxFilesystemsExplained)) this is most likely the cause of your problem. Running your program on a system or partition with a different file system would tell you for sure.

Comment: @MarcoMariani I saw that, did you see the 2nd and 3rd post?

Comment: There is no file size limit on my account, I check using ulimit command as specified [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/file-size-limit-exceeded-error-under-linux-and-solution/). file size says unlimited

Comment: one possible explanation is in the comment section(2nd comment by username 'Chris') of that [link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/file-size-limit-exceeded-error-under-linux-and-solution/) it says that fat fs only supports upto 4gb file size. the partition I am writing to is fat.

Comment: @viper yes, that seems most likely the cause of your problem then. Can you test your program on a system with a different file system? That way you'd know for sure if you are running into this limit.

Comment: fat32 was the problem. I was able to write beyond 4Gb.

Answer (score 4):

I also got this error when I had too many files in one directory. I had `64435` files in a directory, each with 10 digits + '.json' in their names, and any subsequent attempts to write new files to the directory threw errors (e.g.) `OSError: [Errno 27] File too large: 'ngrams/0/0/0/0000029503.json'`

Answer (score 2):

When files get too large, addressing becomes an issue. Typically you get 32 bits which translates to a maximum size of about 4 gb.