# Python giving OSError: [Errno 27] File too large on very small files with enough disk space/memory available

Tags: python, docker, filesize, oserror

I have an application that creates several very small temporary files as part of unit tests or specific functionality.
I started experiencing more often "random" errors `OSError: [Errno 27] File too large`. By random I mean the problem sometimes goes away on reboot or if I re-run the tests after some time later. I manually checked that the temp folder on Mac is cleaned up and has enough memory/space to create such small files. (several GBs available) Small files in this context are for example of size 16384, 58330, 26502 (in bytes) or even less. Shutil.copyfile is used to create these files but it also gives the same error when just doing os.link which should take the minimum space on a disk. I replaced the shutil.copfile (where possible) with os.link to test if it fixes the problem but the effect is same.
On Mac OS, this error is often thrown after some random time of intensively running a lot of tests when I do development. However, the error is persistent all the time when running inside the docker image.

Error snippets:

```
    @pytest.fixture(scope="module")
    def simulate_mirror(fixtures):
        """
        Thjs fixture creates a file/directory structure that simulates an offline PyPI mirror
        Used to test the `mirror://` bandersnatch integration for scanning the whole PyPI repository
        """
        from aura import mirror as amirror

        with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory(prefix="aura_test_mirror_") as mirror:
            pmirror = Path(mirror)
            assert pmirror.is_dir()
            os.mkdir(pmirror / "json")

            for pkg, pkg_files in MIRROR_FILES.items():
                # copy the package JSON metadata
                os.link(
                    fixtures.path(f"mirror/{pkg}.json"),
                    pmirror / "json" / pkg
                )

                for p in pkg_files:
                    os.makedirs(pmirror / p["path"])
                    os.link(
                        fixtures.path(f"mirror/{p['name']}"),
>                       os.fspath(pmirror / p["path"] / p["name"])
                    )
E                   OSError: [Errno 27] File too large: '/analyzer/tests/files/mirror/wheel-0.34.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl' -> '/tmp/aura_test_mirror_a6o5p8fn/packages/8c/23/848298cccf8e40f5bbb59009b32848a4c38f4e7f3364297ab3c3e2e2cd14/wheel-0.34.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl'

tests/conftest.py:204: OSError
```

```
    def test_apip():
        # Test package taken from pip tests
        # https://github.com/pypa/pip/tree/master/tests/data/packages
        whl = Path(__file__).parent /'files' / 'simplewheel-1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl'

        venv_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp(suffix="_pytest_aura_apip")
        # print(f'Virtualenv created in {venv_dir}')
        try:
            # Create virtualenv
            venv.create(
                env_dir=venv_dir,
>               with_pip=True,
                # symlinks=True
            )

tests/test_apip.py:56:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/venv/__init__.py:390: in create
    builder.create(env_dir)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/venv/__init__.py:66: in create
    self.setup_python(context)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/venv/__init__.py:233: in setup_python
    copier(context.executable, path)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/venv/__init__.py:176: in symlink_or_copy
    shutil.copyfile(src, dst)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/shutil.py:122: in copyfile
    copyfileobj(fsrc, fdst)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

fsrc = <_io.BufferedReader name='/usr/local/bin/python'>, fdst = <_io.BufferedWriter name='/tmp/tmpw5gbckwv_pytest_aura_apip/bin/python'>, length = 16384

    def copyfileobj(fsrc, fdst, length=16*1024):
        """copy data from file-like object fsrc to file-like object fdst"""
        while 1:
            buf = fsrc.read(length)
            if not buf:
                break
>           fdst.write(buf)
E           OSError: [Errno 27] File too large

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/shutil.py:82: OSError
```

These errors are also sometimes thrown when creating a virtualenv using `venv.create`. I also always receive sqlite3.OperationalError: disk I/O error inside the docker image which might be related to the same problem.
More technical information:
Mac OS Catalina, fully upgraded, reinstalled python via brew to the latest 3.7.7 + recreated all virtualenv and reinstalled all dependencies. Based on other SO questions ([File too Large python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10956175/file-too-large-python)) I already checked that the file system supports the file size well within the limits and also the maximum number of files allowed in a directory.
Latest commit containing the issue (includes dockerfile that fails with the error):

https://github.com/RootLUG/aura/commit/b4c730693e8f7fd36ab2acc78997694002c4e345

Code locations triggering the error:

https://github.com/RootLUG/aura/blob/dev/tests/conftest.py#L181

https://github.com/RootLUG/aura/blob/dev/tests/test_apip.py#L54

Travis log from the unit tests:

https://travis-ci.org/github/RootLUG/aura/builds/671722230

Answer (score 0):

Does it work outside of Docker? I'm not familiar with how they do it on Macs but on Windows at least, I believe Docker runs in a VM with its own disk space limitations, so perhaps Docker is out of space and that's the issue you're running up against. May be worth looking into that.

Comment: No it doesn't . Sometimes the errors appear outside the docker (Mac virtualenv) but it's less predictable as sometimes they disappear on reboot or just when re-running the tests few minutes later. The Docker image always produces the errors on my system and also in travis as described. I have also tough that it might be something fancy regarding mounted directories or filesystem as from past experience my Linux machine used tempfs  which was a virtual filesystem residing in memory and not on disk. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to debug this or inspect further the problem

Comment: also maybe worth noting I tried changing the fsize ulimit but that didn't have any effect

Comment: Hmm. Not sure what else to tell you, sorry about that.